# How can I convert a string to a float in mysql?

Tags: mysql, type-conversion

I have a table containing latitude and longitude values stored as strings (`VARCHAR`) which I'd like to convert to `FLOAT (10,6)`.

However there doesn't appear to be a straightforward way to do this using `CAST()` or `CONVERT()`.

How can I convert these columns easily? This is a one-time conversion.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It turns out I was just missing `DECIMAL` on the `CAST()` description:

> **`DECIMAL[(M[,D])]`**
>
> Converts a value to DECIMAL data type. The optional arguments M and D specify the precision (M specifies the total number of digits) and the scale (D specifies the number of digits after the decimal point) of the decimal value. The default precision is two digits after the decimal point.

Thus, the following query worked:

```
UPDATE table SET
latitude = CAST(old_latitude AS DECIMAL(10,6)),
longitude = CAST(old_longitude AS DECIMAL(10,6));
```

Answer (score 25):

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(4 AS DECIMAL(4,3));
+-------------------------+
| CAST(4 AS DECIMAL(4,3)) |
+-------------------------+
|                   4.000 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CAST('4.5s' AS DECIMAL(4,3));
+------------------------------+
| CAST('4.5s' AS DECIMAL(4,3)) |
+------------------------------+
|                        4.500 |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CAST('a4.5s' AS DECIMAL(4,3));
+-------------------------------+
| CAST('a4.5s' AS DECIMAL(4,3)) |
+-------------------------------+
|                         0.000 |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Don't put a space between `CAST` and `()` like I did. It will lead you to `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax`

Answer (score 22):

This will convert to a numeric value without the need to cast or specify length or digits:

`STRING_COL+0.0`

If your column is an `INT`, can leave off the `.0` to avoid decimals:

`STRING_COL+0`

Comment: Converts to integer, not decimal.

Comment: @RogerDueck Can you provide an example that yields an INT type?

Comment: Correction: converts to integer instead of decimal in some cases. Example: `CREATE TABLE t (j json); INSERT INTO t VALUES ('{"a":"1.23"}'); SELECT j->"$.a"+0 FROM t;`, should give `1.23`, but result is `1`.

Comment: Try: `+0.0` instead of `+0`