# How to get a float result by dividing two integer values using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, division, rounding

Using T-SQL and Microsoft SQL Server I would like to specify the number of decimal digits when I do a division between 2 integer numbers like:

```
select 1/3
```

That currently returns `0`. I would like it to return `0,33`.

Something like:

```
select round(1/3, -2)
```

But that doesn't work. How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Have you tried 1.0 / 3 ?

Answer (score 399, accepted):

The suggestions from stb and xiowl are fine if you're looking for a constant.  If you need to use existing fields or parameters which are integers, you can cast them to be floats first:

```
SELECT CAST(1 AS float) / CAST(3 AS float)
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(MyIntField1 AS float) / CAST(MyIntField2 AS float)
```

Comment: Or you can cast them as decimals, if you want a decimal result.

Comment: SELECT 1.0*MyInt1/MyInt2

Comment: @TroubleZero for MySQL use `decimal`

Comment: thanks a lot, you saved my day. I was tried CAST(7/3 AS float) but returned 2 again. So cast numbers is solved my problem.

Comment: no need to cast both dividend and divisor, see @M.S.' answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30639343/2866644

Comment: Anyone who is looking for help for DB2, this will work. For whatever reason, DECIMAL() does not work properly.

Comment: And if you're trying to store it into a variable or cell, make sure your variable/cell is a float data-type

Answer (score 90):

Because SQL Server performs integer division. Try this:

```
select 1 * 1.0 / 3
```

This is helpful when you pass integers as params.

```
select x * 1.0 / y
```

Comment: You can even leave out the zeroes.

Answer (score 59):

It's not necessary to cast both of them. Result datatype for a division is always the one with the higher [data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx). Thus the solution must be:

```
SELECT CAST(1 AS float) / 3
```

or

```
SELECT 1 / CAST(3 AS float)
```

Answer (score 35):

use

```
select 1/3.0
```

This will do the job.

Answer (score 19):

I understand that `CAST`ing to `FLOAT` is not allowed in MySQL and will raise an error when you attempt to `CAST(1 AS float)` as stated at [MySQL dev](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).

The workaround to this is a simple one. Just do

```
(1 + 0.0)
```

Then use `ROUND` to achieve a specific number of decimal places like

```
ROUND((1+0.0)/(2+0.0), 3)
```

The above SQL divides 1 by 2 and returns a float to 3 decimal places, as in it would be `0.500`.

One can `CAST` to the following types: **binary, char, date, datetime, decimal, json, nchar, signed, time,** and **unsigned**.

Comment: MySQL does allow `CAST`, it just doesn't allow casting to `FLOAT`. Cast to `DECIMAL` instead. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368163/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-a-float-in-mysql.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like this trick works in SQL Server and is shorter (based in previous answers)

```
SELECT 1.0*MyInt1/MyInt2
```

Or:

```
SELECT (1.0*MyInt1)/MyInt2
```

Comment: I liked this the most, it even looks nice for percentage calculations:
`SELECT 100.0 * @Elapsed / @Total`

Answer (score 3):

### Use this

`select cast((1*1.00)/3 AS DECIMAL(16,2)) as Result`

Here in this sql first convert to float or multiply by 1.00 .Which output will be a float number.Here i consider 2 decimal places. You can choose what you need.

Answer (score 3):

If you came here (just like me) to find the solution for **integer value**, here is the answer:

```
CAST(9/2 AS UNSIGNED)
```

returns 5

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised to see `select 0.7/0.9` returning `0.8` in Teradata given they're already as floats/decimal numbers! I had to do `cast(0.7 as float)` to get the output that I was after.

Answer (score 0):

When using literals, the best way is to "tell" SQL
which type you mean.

if you want a decimal result, add decimal point ".0" to your numbers:

```
SELECT 1.0 / 3.0
```

| Result |
| --- |
| 0.333333 |

---

if you want a float (real) result, add "e0" to your numbers:

```
SELECT 1e0 / 3e0
```

| Result |
| --- |
| 0.333333333333333 |