# SQL SERVER round up to the nearest tenth and to the whole number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to convert a calculation from VBS to Sql server to the whole number and the nearest tenth.  This is the calculation on VB:

```
 a=2/28/2016
    b=6/15/2016
    d=1
    Days360(a, b) = 107
    -INT(-(10^d)*DAYS360(a,b)/30)/(10^d) =
    -INT(-(10^1)*107/30)/(10^1) =
    -INT(-10*107/30)/10 =
    -INT(-1070/30)/10 =
    -INT(-35.666667)/10 =
    -(-36)/10 =
    36/10 = 3.6 --- result for nearest tenth

a=2/28/2016
b=6/15/2016
d=0
Days360(a, b) = 107
-INT(-(10^d)*DAYS360(a,b)/30)/(10^d) =
-INT(-(10^0)*107/30)/(10^0) =
-INT(-1*107/30)/1 =
-INT(-107/30)/1 =
-INT(-3.5666667)/1 =
-(-4)/1 =
4/1 =4  ---result for the whole number
```

How do I convert these two to sql?  I use these two queries but I don't get the results I expected:

```
SELECT ROUND(DATEDIFF(day,'2016-02-28','2016-06-15')*10/30/10,0) AS DiffDate
SELECT ROUND(DATEDIFF(day,'2016-02-28','2016-06-15')*10/30/10,1) AS DiffDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some versions of SQL server have the following behaviour when dealing with literals:

Any non-enclosed numeral with no decimal point is an `integer constant`. When dividing two integers, the result is by default an integer, so the expression might get evaluated to `107 * 10 / 30 / 10 => 1070 / 30 / 10 => 35 / 10 => 3` with the usual precedence rules. Try using floating-point constants and observe the results. (E.g. write `10.0` instead of `10` )

See also this page for more information about constants: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx. Or see this SO question: [How to get a float result by dividing two integer values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719044/how-to-get-a-float-result-by-dividing-two-integer-values)

Comment: This is true but you don't have to add decimal places to every literal in the calculation. Just adding a decimal point after the first 10 is adequate for this. SELECT ROUND(DATEDIFF(day,'2016-02-28','2016-06-15')*10./30/10,0) AS DiffDate

Comment: SELECT ROUND(DATEDIFF(day,'2016-02-28','2016-06-15')*10./30/10,0) AS DiffDate gives me the result "4.000000000"

Comment: This query gives me the result "4":  SELECT ROUND(DATEDIFF(day,'2016-02-28','2016-06-15')*CAST(10 AS float)/CAST(30 AS float)/CAST(10 AS float),0) AS DiffDate