# Computing value in select statement t-sql

Tags: sql, ssms

I am trying to compute a value in select statement itself but surprisingly it results in 0.

```
SELECT Top(1) Name, 
LEN(Name) AS Equals, 
Abs(LEN('Johny') - LEN(Name)) AS NotEquals, 
LEN(Name)/(Abs(LEN('Johny') - LEN(Name)) + LEN(Name)) As Match
FROM Demo
WHERE Name = LEFT( 'Johny' , LEN(Name) ) 
ORDER BY LEN(Name) DESC
```

Output:

```
Name    Equals  NotEquals   Match
John    4           1         0
```

Why exactly is value of `match` field `0` in output?

Comment: Because you do integer devision which cuts off the digits after the comma. And a result smaller than 1 is 0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get a float result by dividing two integer values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719044/how-to-get-a-float-result-by-dividing-two-integer-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to divide integer values where divisor > dividend

try cast one value to float

```
SELECT Top(1) Name, 
LEN(Name) AS Equals, 
Abs(LEN('Johny') - LEN(Name)) AS NotEquals, 
cast(LEN(Name) as float)/(Abs(LEN('Johny') - LEN(Name)) + LEN(Name)) As Match
FROM Demo
WHERE Name = LEFT( 'Johny' , LEN(Name) ) 
ORDER BY LEN(Name) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your calculation uses integers:

```
4/5 = 0
```

All behind the comma is removed

Answer (score 2):

It's this:

```
LEN(Name)/(Abs(LEN('Johny') - LEN(Name)) + LEN(Name)) As Match

4 / ((5 - 4) + 4)

4/ (1 + 4)

4 / 5

= 0
```