# SQL Server: Why does COUNT(*)/COUNT(Countries) As Hit gives me 0s?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code

```
SELECT 
    Country,  
    COUNT(*) AS Records, 
    COUNT(SpecialField) AS Cnt, 
    COUNT(SpecialField)/COUNT(*) AS Perc_Hit 
FROM 
    Table
GROUP BY 
    Country
ORDER BY 
    Cnt DESC, Records DESC
```

This query returns 0s for the `Perc_Hit` column even though it shouldn't. For example, one China has 1000 'records' and 853 'counts', so I'm expecting .853 as my result.

Can someone tell me why there's this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An INT/INT will return an INT  try  COUNT(SpecialField)/(COUNT(*) +0.0)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti When you hover your mouse over `add a comment` then title is displayed and it reads "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments." -- Please post your answer.

Comment: @Anand Not if  SpecialField contains nulls.  Nulls would be excluded from the count

Comment: Check for null rows in the column you are counting.

Comment: @Anand `count()` doesn't count nulls, so if just 1 row has a null, the result will be zero

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a float result by dividing two integer values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719044/how-to-get-a-float-result-by-dividing-two-integer-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in @JohnCappelletti's comment, you are performing integer division. You can simply add `.0` to either side like so:

```
select 
    Country
  , count(*) as Records
  , count(SpecialField) as Cnt
  , count(SpecialField)/(count(*)+.0) as Perc_Hit 
from Table
group by Country
order by Cnt desc, Records desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

```
COUNT(SpecialField)/COUNT(*) AS Perc_Hit
```

to this:

```
CAST(COUNT(SpecialField) as float)/CAST(COUNT(*) as float) AS Perc_Hit
```