# sum divisor returning 0

Tags: sql-server, sum, division

I have this table that i will populate with random figures:

```
|--week--||-2016-||-2017-|
|  1     || 26734||6314916|
|  2     || 64565||9876768|
|  3     || 32243||9976757|
```

what I want to do is create a fourth column that is basically a variance of these numbers.
I created the script below which I know works as I had created it from for another table, there's no difference between these tables apart from the figures in them.

```
 select CAST(ROUND(sum (([2017]) /(([2016]))-1)*100, 0) as NUMERIC(36,0))  as [variance%]
```

from table2

I get the below

```
|--week--||-2016-||-2017-| variance%
|  1     || 26734||6314916|0
|  2     || 64565||9876768|0
|  3     || 32243||9976757|0
```

why am i getting zeros when the other table i had delivers the actual results for variances?

Comment: Use `[2017]*1.0` instead of just `[2017]`

Comment: _Why_ > Because you are doing integer calculus. Convert or cast the integer columns to float or decimal type as needed first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a float result by dividing two integer values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719044/how-to-get-a-float-result-by-dividing-two-integer-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is mould your INT into float value. Something like this :

```
select 
CAST(ROUND(sum (([2017]*1.0) /(([2016]))-1)*100, 0) as NUMERIC(36,0))  as [variance%]
```

read [this stack exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48344/dividing-in-sql) answer to know more about this.