# SQL Query returning 0 when there is data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT
    a.IA
  , a.PC
  , a.LC
  , a.CXPevalCnt
  , ((a.IA / nullif(a.CXPevalCnt,0))*0.35) as IAcalc
  , ((a.LC / nullif(a.CXPevalCnt,0))*0.5) as legacalc
  , ((a.PC / nullif(a.CXPevalCnt,0))*0.15) as pccalc
  , (
      ((a.IA / nullif(a.CXPevalCnt,0))*0.35)
    + ((a.LC / nullif(a.CXPevalCnt,0))*0.5)
    + ((a.PC / nullif(a.CXPevalCnt,0))*0.15)
  ) as Compliance 
FROM 
(
  SELECT
      SUM(IA) as IA
    , SUM(PC) as PC
    , SUM(LC) as LC
    , SUM(CXPevalcount) as CXPevalCnt
  FROM
    tblPLOps_Data
) as A
```

Which returns the following data:

```
IA PC   LC   CXPevalCnt  IAcalc  legacalc pccalc  Compliance

15 12   15      15        0.35    0.5        0     0.85
```

If PC is 12 and CXPevlacnt is 15 I cannot figure out why in my query when I add them together cxpevalcount nulls out but only for PC and not when used with IA or LC. I have sliced this query many different ways and can't figure out the issue

any ideas?

Comment: Can you please post some sample data to demonstrate your issue. [How to post a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/).

Comment: `Integer/Integer = Integer`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a float result by dividing two integer values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719044/how-to-get-a-float-result-by-dividing-two-integer-values)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing integer division. 12/15 = 0. If you want to do accurate math you need to multiply one of them by 1.0 or convert to force sql to do numeric division.

```
((a.PC * 1.0) / nullif(a.CXPevalCnt, 0)) * 0.15 as pccalc
```

You would need to do the same for your other columns as well.

Comment: this worked! I must have missed my cast as decimal in the code. thank you!

Comment: Try this. select 12 / 15 That should explain all you need to know about integer division.