# SQL Dividing two SUM() Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Name  | CountWin | CountFail | Failure% |
---------------------------------
TypeA |   100    |   50      |    50    |
TypeB |   100    |   5       |     5    |
TypeC |   100    |   100     |   100    |
TypeD |   100    |    0      |     0    |
```

I am trying to create the above table with sql. The results are not what I expect though.
The results are below

```
 Name  | CountWin | CountFail | Failure% |
---------------------------------
TypeA |   100    |   50      |     0    |
TypeB |   100    |   5       |     0    |
TypeC |   100    |   100     |     0    |
TypeD |   100    |    0      |     0    |
```

The sql code:

```
INSERT INTO #my_temp_table
  select type, date, CountWin, CountFail from myTable

select type, SUM(CountWin) as CountWin, SUM(CountFail) as CountFail, (((SUM(CountFail) / SUM(CountWin)) * 100) as Failure%
FROM #my_temp_table
WHERE date > DATEADD(day, -7, getdate())
GROUP BY type, date
```

Just wondering why my (((SUM(CountFail) / SUM(CountWin)) * 100 is not returning proper values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a float result by dividing two integer values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719044/how-to-get-a-float-result-by-dividing-two-integer-values)

Comment: I agree with the duplicate vote, but I'd use [**this answer from the question**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11719105/6167855) instead of the accepted one. No need to use `CAST` or `CONVERT`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your database is probably doing integer division.  Simply do the calculation as:

```
select type, date, SUM(CountWin) as CountWin, SUM(CountFail) as CountFail,
      SUM(CountFail) * 100.0 / NULLIF(SUM(CountWin), 0) as Failure_percent
FROM #my_temp_table
WHERE date > DATEADD(day, -7, getdate())
GROUP BY type, date;
```

Notes:

- Your `where` clause is using the time on `getdate()`.  More likely you want:  `date > dateadd(day, -7, cast(getdate() as date))`.
- The `NULLIF()` prevents division by 0.
- Your calculation is a ration, not a percent.  Perhaps you intend:  `SUM(CountFail) * 100.0 / NULLIF(SUM(CountWin + CountFail))`

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly.
Wondering why did you do SUM(CountFail) * 100 first? I know it still returns a larger number, but just wondering why the divide wasn't first in your example

Comment: @user20929302 . . . If the division is first, then SQL Server does an integer divide -- and produces an integer (usually 0).  With the multiplication first the value is converted from an integer and the division behaves as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast it to float

```
INSERT INTO #my_temp_table
select type, date, CountWin, CountFail from myTable

select type, SUM(CountWin) as CountWin, SUM(CountFail) as 
CountFail, (((SUM(CountFail) / CAST(SUM(CountWin) as float)) * 100) as 
Failure%
FROM #my_temp_table
WHERE date > DATEADD(day, -7, getdate())
GROUP BY type, date
```

Comment: `::float` is a standard sql feature? it didn't work in `sql server`

Comment: ::float gave a syntax error when I tried to execute my query

Comment: ::float does not work for sql server but i have updated my answer with the right casting