# Formula returning zero instead of correct amount

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT (16/100)*(12200)
```

This query is returning `0` although it should return `1952`. Why ?

Comment: Change it to (16/100.0)*(12200)

Comment: Because `16/100` is `0`. ["If an integer dividend is divided by an integer divisor, the result is an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated."](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/language-elements/divide-transact-sql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a float result by dividing two integer values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719044/how-to-get-a-float-result-by-dividing-two-integer-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because 16/100 is integer, and it rounded off to zero.
Try

```
select CAST(16 AS DECIMAL(20,4))/100*(12200)
```

or better this way, to reduce rounding errors.

```
select CAST(16*12200 AS DECIMAL(20,4))/100
```

Comment: Using only four digits after decimal point can lead to huge rounding errors. If you can accept them, then you can probably accept 0 as a result here too.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek - Depends on what is rounded. If just amounts are rounded, then 4 digits is plenty - and 0 as result is certainly not tolerable. If currency rates or some other (usually floating point) coefficients are rounded, then yes, 4 digits is not sufficient.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Thanx for your comment, that is an important remark. Although,using division always can lead to rounding errors, no matter how many digits you use (e.g. 100/3), it depends on what you can accept, or in this case, I guess author deals with persentages and scale of 4 is more than enough .