# Divide integers and round to 3 decimal places with one cast?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to divide two integers and round to 3 decimal places with only one cast/convert?

All the examples I see `convert` to `decimal`, then `round`. Some cast both numerator and denominator, etc. I've seen `round` with `floor` or `ceiling`, etc.

I just want to use one cast and I'm done.

For example, `1/3 would be 0.333`. `5/3 is 1.667`

I'm doing this to cast that result as `varchar`.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11719044/1132334

Comment: You can eliminate the `cast`/`convert` by multiplying either the numerator or denominator by `1.0`, e.g. `1 * 1.0 / 3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing two int values t-sql has only two possible outcomes:

- error 8134 (division by zero)
- an int value again

It should be sufficient to coerce one of the operands to `numeric`:

```
select round(1.0/3,3,0)
```

To avoid trailing zeroes, another way:

```
select cast(1.0/3 as decimal(18,3))
```

This of course works only with numeric literals. If you have a column or parameter value, a `cast` is still needed.

This feeble attempt at code golf shaves off one more character:

```
select convert(decimal(9,3),1.0/3)
```

Comment: The problem is that this returns `0.333000` and if I cast as `varchar` it will return "0.333000"

Comment: updated. other solutions use both `cast` and `round`, this one works with either round or cast, as was the premise of your question.