# Assign quotient or longer expression to local (real) variable T SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Was floored to learn this, surely I am making and error...

If I `DECLARE` a real (or decimal) local variable I can't assign (`SET`) the value of an expression?  I have to set to a value first then step through the expression.  If I try to "do the math" all at once I get `0`.

So, this works..

```
DECLARE @HitRate real
SET @HitRate = 805499
SET @HitRate = (@HitRate / 847125) * 100
--SET @HitRate = (805499 / 847125) * 100  --But this does not work?
SELECT @HitRate
```

- If I comment out the first 2 `SET` statement and just use the the third I get `0`
- If I use all `3`, I get `0`
- If I `CAST(@HitRate As DECIMAL(9,2))` I get `0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a float result by dividing two integer values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719044/how-to-get-a-float-result-by-dividing-two-integer-values)

Comment: Peter B, Agreed, duplicate, just did not know I was having a float problem, thought it was the expression complexity because it "worked" when I broke it into step.  Really just did a conversion after the first set and got me into float territory.

Comment: Its weird how you accepted the most simple answer that doesn't contains any clarification about the cause since you are asking **why `(805499 / 847125) * 100` returned `0` !!!!** you didn't asked how to do a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is working for me: Try add .00 in the set value.

```
DECLARE @HitRate real
SET @HitRate = 805499.00
SET @HitRate = (@HitRate / 847125.00) * 100.00
--SET @HitRate = (805499 / 847125) * 100  --But this does not work?
SELECT @HitRate
```

[image]

Comment: You got it,  Sorry for being foolish about my CAST.  This works:

Comment: Give the guy time to evaluate your solution (and others); don't beg people to mark your answer as the answer within 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6df65f5849cd582e0b13f52528c4bf5d)you need to make that 805499 to  805499.00 that means int to float

```
DECLARE @HitRate real
SET @HitRate = 805499
SET @HitRate = (@HitRate / 847125) * 100
SET @HitRate = (805499.00 / 847125) * 100.00  --this will  work now
SELECT @HitRate
```

you got 0 because, 805499/847125 = 0.95 but db engine return 0 because it takes it is an integer value that's why when you multiply 100 with 0 it also make output 0

or you could explicitly `cast` like below

```
SET @HitRate = (cast( 805499 as float) / 847125) * 100
```

it will also return  `95.0862`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following statement

```
SET @HitRate = (805499 / 847125) * 100
```

It will return `0` since `805499` and `847125` are integer so the result of the division is integer = `0`.

Based on the [TSQL division official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/divide-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Returns the data type of the argument with the higher precedence.
>
> If an integer dividend is divided by an integer divisor, the result is an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated.

You can check the SQL data types precedence list from the link below:

- [Data type precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

But when you use :

```
DECLARE @HitRate real
SET @HitRate = 805499
SET @HitRate = (@HitRate / 847125) * 100
SELECT @HitRate
```

It will return `95.0862` **since `@HitRate` is of type `real` and it has higher precedence than integer**

Comment: Agreed.  If I "flip it" {SET @HitRate = (847125 / 805499)}  I get 1