# Converting WHILE to CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cross-apply

I have a scalar function which I am converting to TVF.

In the scalar function I have the below `while` statement:

```sql
WHILE @ReviewDueDate < getdate() 
    SET @ReviewDueDate = DATEADD(DAY, 30, @ReviewDueDate)
```

When I put that in the TVF, I use `CROSS APPLY` (got some help in converting) and it gets converted to the below code:

```sql
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES(DATEADD(DAY, 30 * CEILING(( IIF(CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) > CAST(CA1.ReviewDueDate AS TIME), 1, 0) + DATEDIFF(DAY, CA1.ReviewDueDate, GETDATE()) ) / 30.0), CA1.ReviewDueDate))
) CA2(ReviewDueDate)
```

I don't clearly understand the conversion part.
I understand that when `@ReviewDate < getdate()`, 30 days needs to be added to the `@ReviewDate`.
I am kind of lost when I try to understand the converted `CROSS APPLY` code.

Now the hard part for me is:
I have two more while loops as below:

```sql
WHILE @ReviewDueDate < getdate() 
    SET @ReviewDueDate = DATEADD(Month, 6, @ReviewDueDate)
```

```sql
WHILE @ReviewDueDate < getdate() 
    SET @ReviewDueDate = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @ReviewDueDate)
```

So I have to convert it to use it in `CROSS APPLY`.

I am not clear how the find while loop is converted, so I am struggling with the other two.
Any help in explaining the first conversion is appreciated.
If someone can help converting the other two, that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `cross apply` per se. Apparently it was simply used to be able to refer to the calculated expression from multiple places.

The formula in the `cross apply` directly calculates how many 30-days chunks you need to add to `@ReviewDueDate` so that it exceeds `getdate()`:

- Take the day difference in days between `@ReviewDueDate` and today.
- If time of day of `@ReviewDueDate` is greater than time of day of today, add one day to that.
- Divide the resulting number of days by `30.0` to make sure it's not an [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11719044/11683).
- Round it up. That is the number of 30-day chunks you need to add.
- Multiply it by 30 to get the number of days.

This does not nicely translate to non-day intervals such as months or years. For example, this:

```sql
DATEADD(month, 6 * CEILING(( IIF(CAST(getdate() AS TIME) > CAST(CA1.ReviewDueDate AS TIME), 1, 0) + DATEDIFF(month, CA1.ReviewDueDate, getdate()) ) / 6.0), CA1.ReviewDueDate);
```

would be wrong, as it would return the `CA1.ReviewDueDate` unmodified if today's date was in the same month and the `CA1.ReviewDueDate`s time of date was not greater than today's time of day.

So you need to adjust for the difference in days in addition to months/years:

```sql
DATEADD(
  month,
  6 * CEILING(  (IIF(  (day(getdate()) > day(CA1.ReviewDueDate) or CAST(getdate() AS TIME) > CAST(CA1.ReviewDueDate AS TIME)), 1, 0) + DATEDIFF(month, CA1.ReviewDueDate, getdate())) / 6.0  ),
  CA1.ReviewDueDate
)
```

```sql
DATEADD(
  year,
  1 * CEILING(  (IIF(  (month(getdate()) > month(CA1.ReviewDueDate) or day(getdate()) > day(CA1.ReviewDueDate) or CAST(getdate() AS TIME) > CAST(CA1.ReviewDueDate AS TIME)), 1, 0) + DATEDIFF(year, CA1.ReviewDueDate, getdate())) / 1.0  ),
  CA1.ReviewDueDate
)
```

All that strictly assumes that `CA1.ReviewDueDate` is always smaller than `getdate()`. If it's not, you want to wrap the entire thing into another `case when ... end` that handles this case and does something different when it's already past today.

Comment: thanks for giving clear explanation and helping me convert.