# Sorting by Price SQL data type VARCHAR

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to order by price but type is varchar

my query = Select cost FROM table order by cost asc

result :

```
1.100.000
3.400.000
5.500.000
142.000
199.000
238.000
287.500
315.000
380.000
900.000
```

should:

```
142.000
199.000
238.000
287.500
315.000
380.000
900.000
1.100.000
3.400.000
5.500.000
```

How can I do it??

Comment: The only reasonable solution is to change this field to numeric type not string. Can you do it?

Comment: Why would you store numbers in a VARCHAR?

Comment: Actually this may have been a better DUP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368163/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-a-float-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert to a number:

```
order by replace(price, '.', '') + 0
```

Assuming that no prices start with "0" and all have the same format, you can use:

```
order by length(price), price
```